# Will installing two GU10 light bulbs into 2G10 base work?

Tags: voltage, power, lighting, lamp

I have a 2G10 lamp base mounted into the wall with a 2G10 bulb, I want to connect it to my smart home. Will anything go wrong if I plug in two GU10 bulbs into it? Will they even fit? Didn't find much info on 2G10 bases online.

Base specs: 36 W, 230 V, full name 1x36 2G10

Smart bulb specs: 5W, 220-240 V

Upd: thanks everyone for your input! Sorry for posting in the wrong forum

Comment: 2G10 is a 4-pin fluorescent lamp fed from a ballast circuit. GU10 is a 2-pin bulb that connects directly to 230 volts (not via a ballast). Does that sound like they are compatible? Does it sound a safe thing to do? I have no idea if they'll fit of course.

Comment: This question is about the use of electronics, not the design of electronics, therefore it is unfit for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work at all. The 2G10 bas also contains a ballast for fluorescent tubes. The ballast works by sending a spike of very high voltage to start the arc across the florescent tube and then regulates the current to prevent the tube's filaments from overheating. The GU10 is an LED bulb that connects directly to 120/230VAC. Obviously, the led is going to get damaged every time you turn it on, if it even fits in the socket. It might not instantly kill the LED bulb, but will probably drop the lifetime noticeably (Again if it even turns on in the first place).